# Having issues trying to hide side bar while surfing

Tags: internet

Is there a way to hide the bar on the left of the screen which appears when you move your mouse towards the left of the screen?

I can't get a full screen when surfing online.
I'm using ubuntu desktop and the bar I'm referring to is the strip bar that's located on the left of the screen, the one that shows the programs in there.

I'm new to all this so still learning what things are and what they mean.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Which web browser are you using? (Its name appears on the very top line of its window). Please click [edit] and add that information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recent versions of Ubuntu that use GNOME, open the `Settings` panel, and select `Dock`. Enable the "Auto-hide the Dock" option, and the dock won't get in your way any more.

[image]

Comment: many many thanks. ubuntu is new to me so still learning how it works but im liking what i see. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Unity Desktop Environment

You have to open Settings, choose Dock tab and do:

- disable Auto-hide the Dock, so when you will move your cursor to the left side it will not appear hiding content. But your browser window will not take the whole width.
- change icons size so it the left panel will be narrower
- change the Position on screen to the `Bottom`

[image: Main memu]

[image: Settings window]